# Telegram long polling bot on AWS on Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, telegram

I'm from Ukraine! As you know, we have difficult situation with electricity now, so I created a bot for Telegram, that check is the electricity on or off in our house. Bot written on Java + Spring Boot + Hibernate (with MySQL, store some data when electricity become off or on).

Used the most popular API for telegram bots on Java [org.telegrambots](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots), it [spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/tree/master/telegrambots-spring-boot-starter) particularly TelegramLongPollingBot implementation.

I deployed code on AWS on ElasticBeanstalk. Database also stored on AWS RDS (without making backups). Use it Free tire account.

What actually bot do - it has scheduled Spring task (java function), that executes ones  per 30 seconds in next way:

1. Firstly it call some service (that can provide info about electricity in my house) using simple HTTP GET request - actual result;
2. Then it call DataBase to get last row with data about electricity - last remembered result;
3. If actual result is the same as last remembered, function end it execution and wait 30 seconds more. And repeat all.
4. Else it will send appropriate message to telegram chat (electricity off/on) and store new row in DB. This case works twice a day.

That's all a bot do.

Sorry for all this text, hope it needed.
Now my question: today I got email from AWS that I exceeded 85% of the usage limit for one or more AWS Free Tier-eligible services for the month of December.[image]

What actually are those **2,000 Put, Copy, Post or List Requests**? Maybe telegram API make some requests on background or what...
Has anybody problems like this? And how to reduce this calls?

Thanks!

Comment: How does the app authenticate with telegram? If it's doing token requests it could add some overhead. Otherwise, that number makes sense given you could see 2880 per day if running a request every 30 seconds.

Comment: @Tomanow, yes, it makes 2880 requests per day, but it GET requests only, not the Put, Copy, Post or List Requests